# Purely Dynamic forms using play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a Play 2.2 application which gets, thru an external web service, a JSON with field name, type and constraints info ; the content of this JSON can be different every time (though the overall structure stays same, with just the difference in number of fields etc.).
Now the requirement is to render a HTML form based on the field definition received. 
Can someone advise what would be the best way to do this (I don't think the usual play-forms can be very useful here, unless someone can tell how to create a dynamic `Mapping`, `Form` objects).
One of the ideas I had was to send the JSON to client side and use `Angular` to render the form but then I am not sure how will I validate that on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play forms are type-safe, which means that the form contents are statically defined (i.e. a tuple or a case class). You will have to write code to generate the form dynamically and to parse the results.

Generating the HTML for the form is a bit too complex to do in a Scala template. I recommend writing a function in an object to do this, eg:

```
object MyHelpers {
  def makeForm(js: JsObject): Html = {
    val xml = 
    <form method="post">
      { js.values.map { e =>
        <input type=text name={e._1} value={e._2}/>
      }}
    </form>

    Html(xml.toString)
  }
}
```

Then import the function in your template: `@import MyHelpers.makeForm`, and call it at the point in your page where you want the form.

Parse the form result with an `Action` (which in this case must be specified as a POST in your routes file) like so:

```
def myFormHandler(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
  val data = for ((key, values) <- request.body.dataParts) yield {
    // validate and process field
  }

  OK(view.html.myform())
}
```

(If your action is a GET, which you probably don't want, use `parse.asFormUrlEncoded`)

Comment: Thanks Richard, this is similar to what I had in mind but I was afraid to implement it because then I lose all the power that play-forms gives (folding, flash errors, constraints, chaining etc.) and I will be required to handle all this myself. Let me wait and see if someone has any other suggestion (maybe a library or something that I am not aware of), if not then I will mark this as the `answer`

Answer (score 0):

Use freemarker as your templating play-form solution within the Play framework to do it. I did something similar as a proof of concept for a work related project. https://github.com/rabbipal/Play-2.1-Java-MongoDb-Freemarker-Dynamic-Form. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for adding your answer but help me understand how this tempating is different from the one provided by Play!
Is there something special about Freemarker?

Comment: Scala is compiled  and cached, and is executed out of your target directory when you do a "play start" (running in prod mode). What this means is that its not possible to introduce a new form while the application is active. If you run in dev mode (play run), the scala is recompiled on the fly.  Therefore, in order to have a truly dynamic form solution, one that does not require "compiling" when in production mode, you would have to use static html or freemarker.