# Dynamically generate Play 2 (Scala) form based on Activiti List<FormProperty>

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, activiti

I am evaluating Play 2 (Scala) in combination with Activiti. I got stuck while trying to
render Activiti forms. Activiti uses a `List<FormProperty>` to declare the structure of a form. Each
[FormProperty](http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/form/FormProperty.html) represents one field, defining its name, value, type etc.

How can I generate a Play 2 form by looping over the list of these properties?

I have read the [ScalaForms](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms) documentation, but all the examples assume that the form fields are
known at compile time.

In Pseudo-Scala, I would need something like:

```
val dynamicForm: Form[DynamicFormData] = Form(
  mapping(
    // This obviously doesn't work, but just to illustrate the idea...
    for (p <- activitiFormProperties) {
        p.getName -> resolveToPlayMapping(p.getType)
    }
  )(DynamicFormData.apply)(DynamicFormData.unapply)
)
```

where `DyncamicFormData` would be a non-case-class backed by a map data structure.

PS: I am aware that Play 2 gives me all the power to manually loop over my properties in the view template and use `request.body.asFormUrlEncoded` to access the data on POST, but I am particularly interested in using the `play.api.data.Form` class with all its validation, error handling, view-helper infrastructure.

Comment: One of the great *features* of Scala/Play is static type safety.The only way to do what you want dynamically would be to generate code (either source with a compilation step, or JVM bytecode) and then load the dynamically-generated class and use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484772/purely-dynamic-forms-using-play-framework - see if this helps